# Remove elements from vector on given indexes, order does not matter

Tags: c++, vector

What I have is a **vector** of elements, I **do not care about the order** of them.
Than I have `N` indexes (each addressing unique position in the vector) of elements to be removed from the vector. I want the removal be as fast as possible.

Best I could come up with was to store indexes in set (order indexes):

```
std::set<unsigned int> idxs;
for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
    idxs.insert(some_index);
```

And than iterating over the set in reversed order and replacing index to remove by last element of the vector.

```
std::set<unsigned int>::reverse_iterator rit;
for (rit = idxs.rbegin(); rit != idxs.rend(); ++rit) {
    vec[*rit].swap(vec[vec.size() - 1]);
    vec.resize(vec.size() - 1);
}
```

However I was thinking whether there is some more efficient way of doing this since the usage of **set seems a bit overkill** to me and I would love to **avoid sorting** at all.

**EDIT1:**
Let us assume I use vector and sort it afterwards.

```
std::vector<unsigned int> idxs;
for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
    idxs.push_back(some_index);
std::sort(idxs.begin(), idxs.end());
```

Can I push it any further?

**EDIT2:** 
I should have mentioned that the vector will have up to 10 elements. However the removal in my program occurs very often (hundreds of thousands times).

Comment: Usually when you want to sort something, you use `std::sort`.

Comment: 2 ways I can think of:  1. iterate and create a new vector of the elements not in your index list. 2. define a functor and use `erase_if` and call your functor which would compare the index and erase this way.

Comment: @EdChum There's no such thing as `erase_if`.

Comment: @T.C. Sorry [`remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

Comment: How big are these vectors, if they are small then creating a new vector from the valid indices should be trivial and fast

Comment: @EdChum `remove_if` probably won't play well with predicates that tests the *address* (or index) of the element rather than its value, since it will move the elements around.

Comment: Quite small, up to 10 elements. However in my program this removal occurs very often, that is the reason for efficiency concerns.

Comment: @T.C. Hmm, yes that is true. I'd just create a new vector of the valid entries in that case and clear the old one

Comment: @Jendas in that case just create a new one of the valid entries, 10 is nothing

Comment: Swap the index element with the last one, and then call `vector.pop_back()`

Comment: For such a small set of items, why don't you use a simple bit mask to track which elements in your small vector are deleted or not? If adding new ones, simply pick the next free bit as index (some bit twiddling will give you this..) and then set it, to delete, simply turn off that bit in the mask.

Comment: @EdChum well the thing is, that the objects stored in vector are quite big but I suppose that if keep some preallocated vector and perform only swaps, it might be fast.

Comment: user Nim's suggestion is a good one, just track the invalid entries and swap these out when adding a new entry. Then your vector won't keep having to be recreated and you simply invalidate the old entries and overwrite these with the new ones.

Comment: But I need to iterate over the vector also. Wouldn't it be too slow?

Comment: No iteration would still be fast, the element type is irrelevant on the speed of iteration and dereferencing

Comment: If you need to push your idea still further, you can allocate the array of indexes on the stack instead of on the heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set` is a good choice. I'd guess using another allocator (e.g. arena)would have the biggest impact. Why not use a set instead of a vector of elements to begin with?

I see the following relevant variations:

- Instead of remove, create a new vector and copy preserved elements, then swap back.
  This keeps your indices stable (unlike removal, which would require sorting or updating the indices).
- Instead of a vector of indices, use a vector of bools of the same length as your data. 
  With the length of "maximum 10" given, a bit mask seems sufficient

So, roughly:

```
struct Index 
{
   DWORD removeMask = 0;  // or use bit vector for larger N
   void TagForRemove(int idx) { removeMask |= (1<<idx); }
   boll DoRemove(int idx) const { return (removeMask & (1<<idx)) != 0; }
}

// create new vector, or remove, as you like
void ApplyRemoveIndex(vector<T> & v, Index remove)
{
   vector<T> copy;
   copy.reserve(v.size());
   for (i=0..v.size())
     if (!remove.DoRemove(i))
       copy.push_back(v[i]);
   copy.swap(v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `swap`/`pop_back` to remove an item at a given index, and keep track of which indices you've moved with a hash table. It's linear space & time in the number of removals.

```
std::vector<T> vec = ...;
std::vector<unsigned int> idxs;
std::unordered_map<unsigned int, unsigned int> map;

for(auto index : idxs) {
  unsigned int trueIndex = index;
  while (trueIndex >= vec.size()) {
    trueIndex = map[trueIndex];
  }

  // element at index 'vec.size()-1' is being moved to index 'index'   
  map[vec.size()-1] = index; 
  swap(vec[trueIndex], vec[vec.size()-1]);
  vec.pop_back();   
}
```

Comment: I don't really think your code is valid since you don't use the trueIndex at all. But perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks for spotting.